# Git reports untracked .gitignore file, that does not exist

Tags: git, gitignore

How to resolve following situation:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        htdocs/files/.gitignore

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git rm htdocs/files/.gitignore
fatal: pathspec 'htdocs/files/.gitignore' did not match any files
```

The `.gitignore` file under `htdocs/files` actually **does not exist**:

```
$ cd htdocs/files/

$ ls -ls
total 0
   0 drwxr-xr-x    3 Trejder  Administ        0 Jun  2 23:53 audios
   0 drwxr-xr-x    3 Trejder  Administ        0 Jun  2 23:53 files
   0 drwxr-xr-x    3 Trejder  Administ        0 Jun  2 23:53 photos
   0 drwxr-xr-x    3 Trejder  Administ        0 Jun  2 23:53 videos
```

(there are, however `.gitignore` files under each of listed folders, but I doubt, that this matters in this case)

I don't know, why git has any record about non-existing `htdocs/files/.gitignore`? How to resolve this?

Comment: The `ls -ls` command wouldn't show a .gitignore file. Use `ls -lsa` to verify there is not .gitignore.

Comment: You can't `git rm` an untracked file. You would just `rm` it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `.gitignore` starts with a period, bash considers it as a "hidden" file. This means that you need to use the `-a` option with `ls` in order to see it: `ls -la`. You can view the contents of the file with `less .gitignore`.

Comment: Your answer explains, why I can't see the file with `ls -ls` and how to resolve this problem (find file with `ls -la` and remove it). But, it does not explain, why Git reports `fatal: pathspec 'htdocs/files/.gitignore' did not match any files`, if file actually exists? Is it, because `git rm` ignores hidden files?

Comment: Ah, I see... _hobbs_' comment cleared my mind-path! :] `git rm` objects, because it works on tracked files only. Since my `.gitignore` is untracked, it "does not exist" for `git rm`.

Answer (score 1):

Forget Git. Just bash it.

```
rm htdocs/files/.gitignore
```